# How can I find additional funding for my extra year of PhD in Europe

Tags: phd, funding, italy

I am a third year (3 of 3) PhD student in Italy. I was so stupid during my first year and lost a lot of time, because I didn't put much effort. 
Now, my professor says that my current results are not sufficient even for making a publication (I need at least one publication), so I have to take a fourth year if I want to finish. In this case, the fourth year will not be funded. 
My question is: are there any possibilities to find any funding outside of the University?

Comment: Are there any companies in industry that might be interested in your results?

Comment: @J.Roibal I didn't do the research in the industry field. Thank you for giving me idea ;-)